# Hotkey to run program or activate/toggle

Tags: autohotkey

I am fairly new to the autohotkey program but I love the functionality of it all.
I am looking to create a hotkey to open a program (if it's not already open) but it's open to activate the window.
I've tried the below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
^+e::
#IfWinExist, ahk_class XLMAIN ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
{
      WinActivate ahk_class XLMAIN ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
}
return
#IfWinExist
#IfWinNotExist, ahk_class ahk_class XLMAIN ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
{
run C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
}
#IfWinNotExist
return
```

Also, could you confirm if mouse positions do not work on dual screen or windows 10?

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: >"Also, could you confirm if mouse positions do not work on dual screen or windows 10?"<
Ask that as a separate question; I have a bit of a longer answer for it and don't think it would be appropriate to tag it along to my answer for the first question. But tl;dr: yes, it is definitely possible in theory, but it takes a bit of effort to make it work in practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. I fixed the syntax and logic for the code. Please try to avoid using the #If statements (especially if you are new) as those tend to break scripts.
2. Don't use *both* ahk_class and ahk_exe at the same time for IfWinActive, as that would be redundant (and nonfunctional as far as I am aware).
3. Double check that the location of your EXCEL.EXE is where you say it is in your script (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE`), because on my computer it was located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE`.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
^+e::
IfWinExist, ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
{
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.
    WinMaximize  ; same
    Send, Some text.{Enter}
    return
}else{
    run C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
}
return
```

Comment: #Directives are very good to use, and their usage should be encouraged. They just have to used correctly. They could be used in this script as well, but there's no need to really. Also bracket placement hardly matters, it's mostly just personal preference. Only in some legacy AHK statements it'll cause problems (IfWinExist is legacy and shouldn't be used)